# Is there a way to limit the fields returned from GET /me/accounts?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I use 'GET /me/accounts' to return the list of pages that a user is the admin of, I get way too much data that uses the same identifier for many unrelated fields (i.e. "name" is used for both categories and the page name).  This makes it almost impossible to parse the data.  Is there a way to limit what the api returns so I just get a list of page names, page id's and the page access token?

I am making the api call using RestSharp as follows:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim usertoken As String = hiddenuseraccesstoken.Value

        Dim client As New RestClient("https://graph.facebook.com")
        Dim pagesrequest = New RestRequest("/me/accounts" & "?access_token=" & usertoken, Method.GET)
        Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(pagesrequest)
        Dim textresponse As String = response.Content
        TextBox2.Text = textresponse
    End Sub
```

The response is:

```
"{"data":[{"access_token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","category":"Real Estate Agent","category_list":[{"id":"555559023685716","name":"Real Estate Agent"},{"id":"5555518281071392","name":"Local Service"}],"name":"Realtor Group","id":"444448043920986","tasks":["ANALYZE","ADVERTISE","MODERATE","CREATE_CONTENT","MANAGE"]}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"ODk1MDE4MDQzOTIwOTg2","after":"ODk1MDE4MDQzOTIwOTg2"}}}"
```

I only need the page name(s), page id(s) and page access token(s).  Is there a way to limit what the api returns here so that is what I get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize declarative fields to do so:

```
/me/accounts?fields=name,id,access_token
```

Comment: My current API call that yields too much data looks like: 'httgps://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=XXXXXXXXX'.  How can I add the declarative fields.  I have tried 'httgps://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=XXXXXXXXX?fields=name,id,access_token' but with no luck.

Comment: I got it.  'httgps://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&fields=id,name,access_token of course with the "g" omitted from httgps works great.  Thanks.